# How can I incorporate Koldunic Sorcery in Vampire: The Requiem?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, conversion, vampire-the-requiem

I'm looking for a method to use the Masquerade blood magic, Koldunic Sorcery, in my Requiem game. I've taken a look on the Translation Guide, but there's no mention of it there, so I'm stumped.
In short, I am looking for one of three things, in this order:

1. A pointer to an official book concerning this particular port, or relevant to it;
2. A ready-made port by someone else;
3. A functional idea about how to easily and efficiently accomplish the port by myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rough-do-it-yourself-conversion:

1. The branching nature of blood magic paths (as seen in the gazillion paths that the Tremere had) doesn't exist in Requiem. The disciplines that come closest to resemble them are Cruac or Thebian Sorcery (& Gilded Cage in a lesser way, since it's restricted to a location). This means that we will not talk about the "The way of Water" or "The way of Fire", there is only Koldunic Sorcery.
2. The powers of those paths then become a ritual of equal level. So "Grasping Soil" the level 1 path power of "The way of Earth" becomes a level 1 ritual. Do note that some jury-rigging will be necessary here since some powers refer consequences that can be avoided by rolls with a difficulty lower then 8 (for example Hungry Earth refers to a roll soak difficulty of 7).
3. Nothing needs to be done fore existing Koldunic rituals (except for the dice fudging if any)

For flavour reasons I would keep the discipline as out-clan (so to increase it would be 7xNewDots, a new ritual is 2xNewDots). Each use would cost 1 Vitae.

With regards to the Dice pool we have some options:

- Copy the dice pool of Cruac (to which Koldunic Sorcery feels like a next door neighbour)
- Try to maintain Old World of Darkness flavour by using the "Path Attribute" + Occult + Koldunic Sorcery. So casting "Kupala's Fury" would be Stamina + Occult + Koldunic Sorcery, while "Wattery Haven" would be Wits + Occult + Koldunic Sorcery. Casting "Invoke the Lesser Sign of Power" would be Intelligence + Occult + Koldunic Sorcery (rituals of Koldunic Sorcery used Intelligence as default attribute).

For example:

- I have Koldunic Sorcery at 2 and know Pool of Lies (Level 1) and Wattery haven (Level 2).
- Now I want to learn Fiery Courage (Level 1). This costs me 2 xp.
- We game some more and I increase my Koldunic Sorcery to 3, this costs 21 xp.
- I can't learn Kupala's Fury (Level 5), since I only have Koldunic Sorcery at 2.

Comment: I don't think this answer is very useful. V20 version has nothing to do with the question, looking in forums is a very vague suggestion unless you can link a specific post somewhere and even though I'm fairly familiar with both Masquerade and Requiem, I can't decipher your DIY version. Sorry, but as it is I don't see the answer as helpful - XP calculations are actually the easiest to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

### Consider *Blood Sorcery: Sacraments and Blasphemies*.

Koldunic magic is, in a few words, corrupting, wild and pagan — and that gives it kinship to Crúac. *Blood Sorcery: Sacraments and Blasphemies* gives systemic guidelines for crafting custom Crúac rituals (and Theban Sorcery, too) based on a set of themes like Creation, Transmutation, Destruction and so on. Using the mechanics in this book, it would be not too much work to build out the existing Koldunic Sorcery Paths and Rituals. There's even flavor elements of dealing with lesser and greater spirits and gods.